# How can I replace the nmblookup command on Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, smb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is nmblookup in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24972/where-is-nmblookup-in-lion)

In Snow Leopard, I used to use the command
`nmblookup -U 172.16.0.10 -R domainPC | grep '<00>' | awk '{print $1}'`
Blindly upgrading to Lion, I didn't realize that Apple removed SMB I am now in trouble.

Is there anyway to replace it with an alternative? I see there is `smbutil lookup [hostname]`, but I am not sure if I can add a gateway like I did with `nmblookup`.

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24972/10193

Comment: Actually it goes beyond the other question, as it asks how to specify the host to query... But then again the man page answers that - anyway, I want the bounty ;) which was like 100 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the man page?

Shouldn't `smbutil lookup [-w host] name` do the job?

> ```
>  Global options are as follows:
>  -h      Print a short help message.
>  -v      Verbose output.
>  The commands and local options are:
>  help command
>          Print usage information about command.
>  lookup [-w host] [-t node_type] [-e] name
>          Resolve the given name to an IP address.  The NetBIOS name server can be directly specified via
>          the -w option. The NetBIOS name type can be specified via the -t, the default is to lookup file
>          servers. For a complete list of name type please see "http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163409".
>          The NetBIOS names will be unpercent escaped out if the -e option is specified.
>  status [-ae] hostname
>          Resolve given hostname (IP address or DNS name) to NetBIOS workgroup and system name. All Net-
>          BIOS names will be displayed if the -a option is specified. All NetBIOS names will be percent
>          escaped out if the -e option is specified.
> ```

For me this worked (replacing your example):

`smbutil lookup -w 172.16.0.10 -e domainPC | awk '/IP address of/ {print $5}'`

Comment: The -R says it is illegal when I run it although smbutil lookup [-w host] name does work

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste error: should be -e instead of -R, modified the answer